# Iterating Over JSON Data (weird results)

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a family Tree using JSON data then iterating over that and displaying each member of the family with relevant details on the web page. The problem seems to be that the data is getting mixed up somewhere. For example, where I set that date that a family member died, it's getting mixed up and passed out onto the web page under the wrong person.

Here is my JS code:

```
function family(data) {
  var xhttp, jsonData, parsedData;

  // check that we have access to XMLHttpRequest
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

     // get the data returned from the request...
     jsonData = this.responseText;
     // ...and parse it
     parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

         displayData(parsedData);

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", data, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function displayData(data) {
  var div, name, dob, died, spouse, mother, father;

  data.forEach(function(member){

    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = member.name.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();

    name = document.createElement('h1');
    name.innerText = member.name;

    dob = document.createElement('p');
    dob.innerText = member.dob;

    if(member.died !== null) {
      died = document.createElement('p');
      died.innerText = member.died;
      div.appendChild(died);
    }

    if(member.spouse !== null) {
      spouse = document.createElement('p');
      spouse.innerText = member.spouse;
    }

    if(member.parents !== null) {
      mother = document.createElement('p');
      mother.innerText = member["parents"]["mother"];
      father = document.createElement('p');
      father.innerText = member["parents"]["father"];
      div.appendChild(mother);
      div.appendChild(father);
    }

    div.appendChild(name);
    div.appendChild(dob);

    div.appendChild(spouse);


    var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    document.body.insertBefore(div, scriptTag);

  });

}

family('family.json');
```

And my JSON data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "gender": "male",
    "dob": "12 August 1940",
    "died": null,
    "parents": null,
    "spouse": "Betty Smith"
  },
  {
    "name": "Betty Smith",
    "gender": "male",
    "dob": "23 September 1937",
    "died": null,
    "parents": null,
    "spouse": "John Smith"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe Smith",
    "gender": "male",
    "dob": "14 August 1960",
    "died": "20 November 2004",
    "parents": {
      "mother": "Betty Smith",
      "father": "John Smith"
    },
    "spouse": null
  }
]
```

Is there a better way to structure the JSON? More importantly, what am I doing wrong that's causing the the wrong details to be applied? My guess is it's either a) because my for in loop doesn't include child objects, or that it has something to do with instances, though I doubt that latter is the real reason. Just a bit overwhelmed at this point! Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: put the variables definition `var div, name, dob, died, spouse, mother, father;` inside `data.forEach` loop. The way you defined it causes problem with on every iteration the previous data will be appended or replaced by new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the order wrong (for example: if a person is dead, the date of death will be printed before the name (which is a `h1` which will be confusing because it will look like the date of death belongs to the previous person).

You'll have to append the element just after they were created (where the `/********/`) like:

```
div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = member.name.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();    

name = document.createElement('h1');
name.innerText = member.name;
/********************/
div.appendChild(name);

dob = document.createElement('p');
dob.innerText = member.dob;
/*******************/
div.appendChild(dob);

if(member.died !== null) {
  died = document.createElement('p');
  died.innerText = member.died;
  div.appendChild(died);
}

if(member.spouse !== null) {
  spouse = document.createElement('p');
  spouse.innerText = member.spouse;
  /*****************/
  div.append(spouse);
}

if(member.parents !== null) {
  mother = document.createElement('p');
  mother.innerText = member["parents"]["mother"];
  father = document.createElement('p');
  father.innerText = member["parents"]["father"];
  div.appendChild(mother);
  div.appendChild(father);
}
```

You wasn't even checking if the spouse exists before appending it which if there wasn't one it will append the spouse of the previous person.

And for clarity try to add a string before the value of the property, something like:

```
died.innerText = "Died: " + member.died;
//...
mother.innerText = "Mother: " + member["parents"]["mother"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You separated creating and appending of `name`, `dob` and `spouse` - that's your problem.

Add line

```
name = dob = died = spouse = mother = father = null;
```

as the first line inside `forEach` - and the code will tell you.

```js
function displayData(data) {
  var div, name, dob, died, spouse, mother, father;

  data.forEach(function(member){

    name = dob = died = spouse = mother = father = null;
    
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = member.name.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();

    name = document.createElement('h1');
    name.innerText = member.name;
    //console.log("append name");
    div.appendChild(name);

    dob = document.createElement('p');
    dob.innerText = "Born: " + member.dob;
    //console.log("append dob");
    div.appendChild(dob);

    if(member.died !== null) {
      died = document.createElement('p');
      died.innerText = "Died: " + member.died;
      //console.log("append died");
      div.appendChild(died);
    }

    if(member.spouse !== null) {
      spouse = document.createElement('p');
      spouse.innerText = "Spouse: " + member.spouse;
      //console.log("append spouse");
      div.appendChild(spouse);
    }

    if(member.parents !== null) {
      mother = document.createElement('p');
      mother.innerText = "Mother: " + member["parents"]["mother"];
      father = document.createElement('p');
      father.innerText = "Father: " + member["parents"]["father"];
      //console.log("append mother");
      div.appendChild(mother);
      //console.log("append father");
      div.appendChild(father);
    }

    document.body.append(div);

  });

}

var testData = [
  {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "gender": "male",
    "dob": "12 August 1940",
    "died": null,
    "parents": null,
    "spouse": "Betty Smith"
  },
  {
    "name": "Betty Smith",
    "gender": "female",
    "dob": "23 September 1937",
    "died": null,
    "parents": null,
    "spouse": "John Smith"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe Smith",
    "gender": "male",
    "dob": "14 August 1960",
    "died": "20 November 2004",
    "parents": {
      "mother": "Betty Smith",
      "father": "John Smith"
    },
    "spouse": null
  }
];

displayData(testData);
```

Comment: Thanks, a combination of the answers worked. Why do you set all the variables to null?

Comment: @RyanMc - to make catching errors easier. Without these `null` assignments, the variables keep values from previous iterations, which may affect the code logic if it relies on these variables having values for the current array item.